# How can I use IdentityServer 4 and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, identityserver4, using

I followed 
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/7_entity_framework.html#database-schema-changes-and-using-ef-migrations
to use SQL Server with IdentityServer 4

Getting error while try creating Database, IdentityServer4

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'is4aspiddb.dbo.AspNetUserClaims'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: Did you start with [the example code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations) or did you try to write your own? If you wrote your own please add it to your question.

Comment: I start with this example code, but I got the tables for the regular identity framework